# problems with checking year = year in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I'm trying to check if 2015=2015 so i can sum the numbers which is sumif(year(A2:A5)=2015,J2:J5) but I got an error that returns nothing not even a zero.

Comment: Are you sure that the 2015 is just 2015? no leading or trailing spaces etc Have you tried using the trim() function to make sure?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put conditions inside the range for SUMIF.

Switch to SUMIFS so you can bracket the dates:

```
=SUMIFS(J:J,A:A,">=" & DATE(2015,1,1),A:A,"<" & DATE(2016,1,1))
```

Comment: thanks it works,but i have a question and that is there a way to use vlookup on sumif